# How to manipulate UIImage pixel by pixel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, user-interface, uiimage

I have a thumbnail in my iOS app over which I am drawing a cloud icon so basically I have a UIImage. Now I Want to fill the cloud with some colour as some process continues like progress bar.

My question is

> 1. How to access this UIImage and manipulate(pixelwise)?
> 2. How to update only the cloud portion as the cloud is an irregular figure, what checks should be there to set the pixels inside the cloud only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a background colour filled UIView that animates inside another UIView which is masked using maskview...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good blog post which describes how to retrieve and update pixel values for an UIImage.

http://www.brandontreb.com/image-manipulation-retrieving-and-updating-pixel-values-for-a-uiimage/.

Or you could also have a look into GPUImage (https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage). This would give you a much better performance and is also great for manipulating still images. I think a custom filter for accomplishing your task would be fairly easy.